# Page.setHtmlContent error with embedded gadgets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

In an attempt to fudge a workaround for the weird "viewers cannot leave comments" issue in google sites*, I wrote the following silly test script:

```
function addComment(e) {
    var currentPage = SitesApp.getActivePage();
    var pageHTML = currentPage.getHtmlContent();
    var newHTML = pageHTML.replace("BEGIN", "BEGIN "+Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
    currentPage.setHtmlContent(newHTML);
};
```

When the user presses the button, the current page content *should* be changed to include the current user's email address right after the word BEGIN (which I manually inserted- if this works I can just stick in a comment tag thingamabob.

This more or less works. The problem is that the setHtmlContent call does all sorts of weird things to the apps script gadget that contains the button in the first place. Here's the gadget before:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Apps+Script'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D499'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Apps+Script+Gadget%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D500'%3D197'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D500'%3D197'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=TbGPi2pnqyuhJ_BfSq_CO5U6FOI" data-origsrc="https://sites.google.com/a/macros/kstf.org/s/AKfycbzEsLBQucXCZZJwEh9c3RYhn81uJucvz3R5vHeJ2w/exec" data-type="maestro" data-props="align:left;borderTitle:Apps Script Gadget;height:200;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:false;" width="500" height="200" style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;"></div>
```

and here it is after:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Gadget'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D499'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Include+gadget+(iframe)%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D500'%3D197'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D500'%3D197'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=CvjXRgodwYVKPvmsyZR7EbHx2uM" data-igsrc="http://0.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=0&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=%2Fa%2Fmacros%2Fkstf.org%2Fs%2FAKfycbzEsLBQucXCZZJwEh9c3RYhn81uJucvz3R5vHeJ2w%2Fexec%3Fmid%3DACjPJvFOqF88RUUrqDeapp1PHF_lI3Xc3g5Hd3euTifzUYeaILmTTlMfBQ13yI_6%26bc%3Dtransparent%26f%3DArial%2C%2BVerdana%2C%2Bsans-serif%26tc%3D%2523444444%26lc%3D%25230033cc&amp;up_scroll=no&amp;w=100%&amp;h=200" data-type="ggs-gadget" data-props="height:200;igsrc:http#58//0.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=0&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=%2Fa%2Fmacros%2Fkstf.org%2Fs%2FAKfycbzEsLBQucXCZZJwEh9c3RYhn81uJucvz3R5vHeJ2w%2Fexec%3Fmid%3DACjPJvFOqF88RUUrqDeapp1PHF_lI3Xc3g5Hd3euTifzUYeaILmTTlMfBQ13yI_6%26bc%3Dtransparent%26f%3DArial%2C%2BVerdana%2C%2Bsans-serif%26tc%3D%2523444444%26lc%3D%25230033cc&amp;up_scroll=no&amp;w=100%&amp;h=200;mid:0;spec:http#58//www.gstatic.com/sites-gadgets/iframe/iframe.xml;up_iframeURL:/a/macros/kstf.org/s/AKfycbzEsLBQucXCZZJwEh9c3RYhn81uJucvz3R5vHeJ2w/exec?mid=ACjPJvFOqF88RUUrqDeapp1PHF_lI3Xc3g5Hd3euTifzUYeaILmTTlMfBQ13yI_6&amp;bc=transparent&amp;f=Arial,+Verdana,+sans-serif&amp;tc=%23444444&amp;lc=%230033cc;up_scroll:no;width:100%;" width="500" height="200" style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;" class="igm"></div>
```

As best as I can tell, the "hey please set this as your HTML" method seems to be doing some chicanery to make certain that the document is properly parsed, but it's getting caught up in a tail-chasing effect of the iframe redirect. If I could hand in some DOM or something similar, this wouldn't be an issue.

Any advice? This was just a kind of exercise to see if I could finesse the visitor comment system anyway, so I'll probably just take another approach.

*: I know about several other ways to handle visitor comments, but this system needs to be able to work on many site pages, for many site authors in an apps domain, without needing complicated setup on the part of the site author. Eventually, I'll use something else (probably a variation on one of the two app engine forum systems I found this morning), but this was a quick stab at an interim solution. Next interim step is to save these data to the site DB and lay out the comments in the gadget itself. Gadget sizing is unsatisfying, however - I'd rather have the comments right in the page instead of in a separate iframe that has its own scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the getEmail() method doesn't work with consumer accounts or when people outside your domain visit the site (unless your script runs as the user accessing the app)

Next, when you change the HTML of a page, it doesn't make the change immediately, but should happen on the next refresh.

Having said that, what you could do is have your script display the comments as well. You can have labels in your script that display previous comments.

Comment: Yeah, I only need the email address of in-domain accounts (these pages won't be open to people outside the domain). The changes definitely didn't show up immediately - I had to either click refresh on the page, or click to a different page and back. What happened was the mangling of the script iframe I referenced above. The underlying issue is using the script to generate comments somehow - I'll eventually just embed them all in the gadget, but the weird embedded iframe look when the comment list gets long is unsatisfying. The scroll bar should be on the page, not the iframe.

Comment: You should not be (unfortunately) relying on the HTML code for the gadget. There are a few workarounds here - one, embed your comments in the sites page itself rather than in the gadget. I've used this with a lot of success where I have some sort of eyecatcher (BEGIN in your case) and replace that with the comment. Otherwise, you can have a large gadget so that you don't see the scrollbar until the page reaches a lot of comments. The third option is to show the comments in the gadget, but show in pages, say 5 or 10 comments at a time.